# .htaccess redirect from one PHP script to another and stop

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to move all my scripts to another domain and redirect some of basic URLs on new ones.
But for one script `ipn.php` on old domain in the root I want redirect to `index.php` on old domain and stop.

I want all URLs been redirected but this one executed on old domain via `index.php`.

Something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.old_domain.com/$1 [L,NC]

# One old script ipn.php to old index.php (it's connected with old PayPal subscriptions)
RewriteRule ^ipn\.php(.*)$                          index.php$1 [L]

# Other URLs on new domain scripts
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$                         http://www.new_domain.com/some_common_script.php$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^splash/1/(.*)$                         http://www.new_domain.com/splash1.php?param=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^splash/2/(.*)$                         http://www.new_domain.com/splash2.php?param=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^splash/3/(.*)$                         http://www.new_domain.com/splash3.php?param=$1 [R=301,L] 

#...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: With a `!` negative `RewriteCond` or a `[L]` final `RewriteRule`, or an assertion `(?!` even.

Comment: Can you provide an example of all possible solutions, because I have tried everything and nothing?

Comment: You need to showcase your current RewriteRule block, otherwise hard to answer generically.

Comment: Maybe new changes will clarify my situation.